# Compute the determinant $\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos x \\ -\sin y & \cos y \end{vmatrix}$ using the Sarrus' rule

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, determinant

I have an exercise that asks to compute the determinant using the rule Sarrus $\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos x \\ -\sin y & \cos y \end{vmatrix}$

The rule is not just for Sarrus $3\times 3$ matrices?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: The rule is just for `3x3` matrices.

Comment: @B.S. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).

Comment: Well, regardless of the usage of the term "Sarrus' rule", at least we have $\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos x \\ -\sin y & \cos y \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos x &0\\ -\sin y & \cos y &0\\ 0&0&1\end{vmatrix}$. So, in some sense the rule for computing 2x2 minors is a special case of Sarrus' rule.

Comment: *The answer is yes.

Answer (score 4):

The Sarrus's rule is just the use of the definition

$$\det A=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\epsilon(\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n a_{k\sigma(k)}$$
where $A=(a_{ij})$ in the case of low number $n$.

In your case $n=2$ there's two permutations in $S_2$: $id $ and the transposition $\tau=(12)$ so the determinant is $$\epsilon(id) a_{11}a_{22}+\epsilon(\tau)a_{12}a_{21}=a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}=\sin x\cos y+\sin y\cos x=\sin(x+y)$$

Comment: Spot on! $+\uparrow+$

Answer (score 1):

Computing the determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix is a special case of computing it for a $3\times 3$ matrix. You have, in general, that $$
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  a_{n1} & \ldots & a_{nn} \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
  1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
  0 & a_{11} & \ldots & a_{1n} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
  0 & a_{n1} & \ldots & a_{nn} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
and thus in your case that $$
\begin{vmatrix} \sin x & \cos x \\ -\sin y & \cos y \end{vmatrix} =
\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \sin x & \cos x \\ 0 & -\sin y & \cos y \end{vmatrix}
\text{.}
$$
If you use the rule of sarrus to compute the determinant of the right hand side, you'll discover that it produces the same expression as using the rule for $2\times 2$ matrices would have.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{vmatrix}
\sin x & \cos x\\ 
 -\sin y & \cos y 
\end{vmatrix}=\sin x\cos y +\sin y \cos x=\sin(x+y)$$